# Questionable Convergence of a Series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

The summation is:

$$
S = \sum_{k \geq 0} f(k) \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-(1- \frac{f(k+1)^2}{f(k)^2})\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta 
$$

Now, we know that $f(k+1) < f(k)$ and as $k$ approaches infinity, $f(k)$ is zero.
Since the following is true, then we know that when $k$ approaches infinity, then on the instances that $1 -\frac{f(k+1)^2}{f(k)^2}=0$, then the integral as $k$ approaches infinity is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore at every instance of time the integral will be less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (but positive).

My question is, assuming that $\sum_{k \geq 0}f(k)$ converges is it safe to say that since:

$$
\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{k \geq 0} f(k) \geq \sum_{k \geq 0} f(k) \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-(1- \frac{f(k+1)^2}{f(k)^2})\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta
$$

Then because the sum on the LHS of the inequality is finite, then the RHS must converge due to it being less than a finite value?

Comment: Are the $f(k)$'s positive?

Comment: @zhw. Yes the $f(k)$'s are positive

Comment: Isn't it clear that the all of the integrals are $<\pi/2$?

Comment: @zhw. It is clear that the integrals are all less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ except when the eccentricity is one (this is the complete elliptic integral of the second kind)

Comment: You really should put $f(k) > 0$ in the hypotheses. Now, we don't need any "elliptic" notions to see every one of those integrands is positive and $< 1,$ right? I'm not sure what the actual question is here. It looks like we are done in a few words.